# sockets loses connect when moving between wifi to 3g

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets

I am developing socket based application.

It is working fine and my socket connection working fine.

But when I am moving between wifi to 3g it loss the socket connection.

Is there any solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

That is to be expected since you will get a new IP address when you switch networks.  You need to handle the disconnect and re-establish the connection

Comment: how can I handle the disconnect and re-establish the connection,please give me example.

Comment: I can't give you a specific example as you haven't shown any code, but essentially when you get the socket disconnection you should re-open the connection to your server as you did in the first place.  This should be a standard part of your code anyway; networks can fail and you need your app to handle that